# ng-blur not working if input type number in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<input autofocus type="number" class="input_pad" ng-blur="someFunction()" only-digits />
```

// Not calling the someFunction() but if type="text" then working

Please provide the solution if any body faced same issue  Thanks

Comment: show `someFunction`

Comment: I done it now sourabh,  thanks for your consideration.  Actually only-digits was doing something wrong there.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it,  Actully i used the only-digits directive there. After remove this its working now.  :-)